# How to unload jQuery which already loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using `wordpress.com`-like blogging service. The problem is, they insert their stuff at the top of `<head>` and it is loading old version of jQuery. I can't control these because it is serviced blogging.

Here is what they inserts (only related things)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://t1.daumcdn.net/tistory_admin/lib/lightbox/css/lightbox.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://t1.daumcdn.net/tistory_admin/assets/blog/tistory-5bd58cc8d7b7dfbfb7f1002c26058b7a1e9fdce4/blogs/style/content/font.css?_version_=tistory-5bd58cc8d7b7dfbfb7f1002c26058b7a1e9fdce4" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://t1.daumcdn.net/tistory_admin/assets/blog/tistory-5bd58cc8d7b7dfbfb7f1002c26058b7a1e9fdce4/blogs/style/content/content.css?_version_=tistory-5bd58cc8d7b7dfbfb7f1002c26058b7a1e9fdce4" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://t1.daumcdn.net/tistory_admin/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<!-->
<script src="https://t1.daumcdn.net/tistory_admin/lib/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<script src="https://t1.daumcdn.net/tistory_admin/lib/lightbox/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    lightbox.options.fadeDuration = 200;
    lightbox.options.resizeDuration = 200;
    lightbox.options.wrapAround = false;
    lightbox.options.albumLabel = "%1 / %2";
</script>
<script>
    var tjQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .tt_article_useless_p_margin p {
        padding-top: 0 !important;
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
        margin-top: 0 !important;
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
<meta name="referrer" content="always">
```

I want to 'unload' the old version of jQuery(and possibly lightbox too) and load newest version of jQuery(that can be achived easily).

But, since I don't have control of these inserts, I can't prevent them to load. So I have to manually 'unload' old jQuery.

Will it be possible to do?

Comment: If you are using WordPress you can remove the scripts from `functions.php` store in your `wp-content/theme/THEME_DIRECTORY` folder. But if you want to remove it manually, just remove the jquery object from the window before loading a new one, by `delete window.jquery`. You can do the same for other plugins, too.

Comment: @Irandoust Unfortunately, it's not wordpress. I said wordpress-like, not wordpress...